# Filter in Laravel showing BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections, eloquent

I have a collection from below query

```
$order = $company->Orders()
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$this->start_date, $this->end_date])
            ->whereNull('is_cancel')
            ->whereNull('is_removed')
            ->whereNull('deleted_at');
```

Now I want to filter out all the orders who are expired

```
$orders = $orders->filter(function($value,$key){
                return  $this->expiry($value) < Carbon::now();
            });
```

above code is throwing error

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder::filter()'
```

I can use `$orders->get()->filter()` but I need to check furthur in the collection for counts and mapping etc, so I dont want to use get here.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does `$this->expiry()` do?

Comment: It's coming from trait, with some condition it will return a date

Comment: You should get that date expressed in SQL instead, as the querybuilder cannot use functions that vary on the model properties like that, unless its constant for all orders.

Comment: I passed `return  Carbon::now() < Carbon::now();` in return, still same error.

Comment: main point is why filter is coming undefined?

Comment: `return Carbon::now() < Carbon::now()` is the same as `return false`. As I said, you cannot use the `filter()` on a querybuilder -- only the collection (which is what you get from using `get()`).

Comment: SO you are saying get is mandatory to use a filter? Are there any other ways to filter out expired orders ? like each()->filter() ?

Comment: Like I said, if you can get the expire-date in SQL, then you can use a standard `where()`/`whereRaw()`.

Answer (score 3):

`filter` is undefined because it is a method defined on the collection, not on the query builder. What you need to do is to get the results before filtering them:

```
$orders = $company
    ->Orders()
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$this->start_date, $this->end_date])
    ->whereNull('is_cancel')
    ->whereNull('is_removed')
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->get()
    ->filter(function($value) {
        return $this->expiry($value) < Carbon::now();
    });
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I had to extend the builder with other queries after the filter. But thanks for the help. There is no way for my problem to get the solution from the query only.  I had to extend relationships, then get and then filter.